# Should we make this general catch-all question a community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I've been looking at [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

The question is a general catch-all question, so naturally, I thought it should be a community wiki. I flagged it (twice) as seen in the following image.

[image: Flagging Summery]

However, nothing was done (even though the flags were both determined helpful).

Now I don't mind flagging it over and over and gaining flag weight for it until I hit 750, but I really think something should be done.

On that note I think the accepted answer should also be a community-wiki.

What do you say?

Comment: I'm searching for the doc on "General Reference" questions.  If someone has a link, can they help me out?

Comment: @Bill, maybe the blog: [Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

Comment: Check out [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), namely "Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration.". I don't see how that question fits, its accepted answer either.

Comment: "Now I don't mind flagging it over and over gaining flag weight for it until I hit 750...", well, I mind, and I'll make sure you *never* hit 750 if you flag this over and over; you will get the "a moderator reviewed this but found no evidence to support it" rejection as per [Bill's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117052/140951) below.

Comment: Obviously, that's the exact reason I posted it here, so I **don't** need to flag it over and over again (don't you people get sarcasm? :o)

Comment: How many times has this question come up, both on meta and in the moderation queue anyway? Good thing you posted here :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't find anything about "general reference" questions that says they need to be made community wiki.

I would definitely disagree that the answer to that question should be made community wiki, since a lot of effort was put into it by a single person.  They deserve the credit and whatever reputation they get from it.

Comment: Agreed, what of the question? No special effort was put there, and it has already received 159 votes (to date). Those votes should not affect the reputation of the one who asked it as a general reference question.

Comment: @Truth I don't see any reason why that question should be made CW.  It's going to be exceedingly rare for moderators to force a question CW unless the OP requests it.

Comment: @Truth Question upvotes are supposed to reflect how useful a question is. Surely a popular general reference question is useful?

Comment: Sure, but seeing as this question is a general catch all, which is bound to have more upvotes, I think no one should benefit from it as it is a "community question". (Also, at least 2 other moderators agree with me as they have approved my flags [even though nothing was done]).

Comment: @Truth If they really agree with you they would have made the posts CW.  The question was asked by one person, not the community.  The "general reference" designation only means that it's referred to in the tag wiki.  That just means it's a particularly common question.  It doesn't require community collaboration and upkeep, so there's no reason to force it to CW.

Comment: @Truth To notice that if the question is set as CW, also the answers for that question becomes CWs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

That questions is extraordinarily shallow. It has been a **link list / poll / survey question from the inception**. Now I realize CW is not meant to rectify this or as an excuse to keep it open. But it's evident that there isn't much community activity over there to bring it into shape.

I didn't want to bring this up myself, as there seemingly had been a lot of flagging drama going on already. But I take exception to the fact that another question was merged in. Two of my answers are now there, both CW. Apart from that they are now super off-topic among the cursorily answers, it's not accepable to have mixed states due to merging.

It's too late to close that question. It's very much a reference question now, even if just by excessive spam linking due to low standards for exact duplicateness. It's useful nonetheless. But it falls flat on being educative. Without examples it's quite pointless to be declared "reference" answer. Even though I can imagine it as appropriate closevoting penalty. It's the equivalent of a LMGTFY for unresearched plz send the codez for parsing html questions. But as documentation, eh?

It can be rewritten, after the now oversimplified question itself has been repurposed again. But I don't feel either OP nor the top-voted links-only answer show much effort and deserve that much rep. I'm not going to lift a finger there, as there's no point in competing against bandwagon voting at this point.

Don't care if this causes more drama, but this question should very much be CW. Retroactively.